# Retrieving city name for onscreen region [Mapbox]

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm relatively new to iOS and Mapbox development. I'm working on an app where a user can freely manipulate a map full of places they have saved.

When they reach a zoom-level that is completely filled by the geography of a city, I would like to display the name of the city which they are viewing in a banner-style view, even if a city label is not within view on the map (as is often the case when zoomed in).

[Here's a screenshot of the UI for context.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6tfI.jpg)

I'm trying to query the Mapbox tileset for the city name using the following code:

```
func mapViewRegionIsChanging(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {

    let zoomLevel = mapView.zoomLevel

    if zoomLevel >= 14.0 {

            // layer identifier taken from layer name in Mapbox Studio
            let layerIdentifier = "place-city-lg-n"

            let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

            let cityName = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: screenRect, styleLayerIdentifiers: Set([layerIdentifier]))

            print(cityName)
    }
```

I think this code doesn't work because the label is not onscreen at the specified zoom level.

I'm wondering if using `visibleFeaturesInRect` is the best approach for my need—is there a better way to retrieve city name regardless of visible elements and zoom level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task I'd recommend using [MapboxGeocoder](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift) from Mapbox. It is for getting information about the city/village.
you can install pod:

> pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift', '~> 0.12'

and use this code:

```
let geocoder = Geocoder.shared

func mapViewRegionIsChanging(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {

    let geocodeOptions = ReverseGeocodeOptions(coordinate: mapView.centerCoordinate)
    geocodeOptions.allowedScopes = [.place]

    let _ = geocoder.geocode(geocodeOptions) { (placemarks, attribution, error) in
        guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
        print(placemark.name)
        print(placemark.qualifiedName)
    }
}
```

you can add your conditions and it really helps to solve your task

Comment: This worked perfectly and now I'm unblocked—thanks so much for your help!